# Azure Graph 403 Authorization_RequestDenied using service principal from VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I have a service principal that is used by VSTS to run an Azure Powershell script. The command i'm trying to call is `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment`. I'm getting the following error message

```
  "Exception": {
     "Request": {
       "Method": "POST",
       "RequestUri": "https://graph.windows.net/********/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6",
       "Properties": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]",
       "Headers": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]"
     },
     "Response": {
       "StatusCode": 403,
       "ReasonPhrase": "Forbidden",
       "Content": {
         "odata.error": {
           "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
           "message": {
             "lang": "en",
             "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
           }
         }
       },
       "Headers": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]"
}
}
```

I've verified that the service principal has read access for role assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this powershell script `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment` doesn't only needs **read access for role assignment with Azure REST API permission** but also needs **Read directory data permission with Azure AD Graph API**.

We can use Fiddler to find out which API does this command calls:

[image]

It means that `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment` needs call 3 APIs to complete the operation. Two of them are Azure REST API, one of them is Azure AD Graph API:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/<tenantID>/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6
```

**Solution:**

So, check if your sp has permissions to read directory data permission.**(You'd better add `Read directory data` permission both Application permissions and Delegated permissions and then click Grant permissions button**). Here is my test result:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,@user9360564 Does this answer helpful?

Comment: This makes sense but the issue doesn't exist when i use a runbook in an automation account. The runbook uses a service principal and has the exact same permissions. I don't believe the module versions are the same but how would this change anything?

Comment: Hi,@user9360564. Maybe one has been granted permissions, the other one hasn't. So, you'd better add the permissions and also click the Grant permssions button.